# Azure Blob Storage PUT request returns no Result Code

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

In Application Insights "Failures" I have dependency failures that have "undefined" or "unknown" status codes.

When I click on them I see that event chain begins by an API call. It makes PUT requests to Azure blob storage. One request has "Call status false" and no result code, always followed by another request that has "Call status true" and "Result code 201" while all other lines of dependency properties are identical.

I don't understand what the "no status code" failures mean or how to deal with them.

Any ideas?

[image: Application Insights - Failures]

Answer (score 1):

When you see an "undefined" or "unknown" status code, it means that Application Insights couldn't capture or didn't receive a specific HTTP status code from the dependency.

it seems that in your case there is a transient failure, which is handled by some retry logic. Some SDKs or clients have built-in retry logic. If an initial request to Azure Blob Storage fails due to transient issues like network blips, timeouts, etc., the SDK might automatically retry the request. The first failed request gets logged as "Call status false" and then the immediate retry is successful with a "Result code 201".

Comment: How would I make sure that it's a transient fault though? The error is happening in up to 0.4-0.8% of API requests (I couldn't find any authoritative source on acceptable threshold).
I'm not specifying any retry policies, so azure blob is probably using its own. Is there any easy way (e. g. querying blob client) to determine that the request has been retried by the default retry policy?